# perfect way to displaying images

Tags: html, css

I am new to css . I am trying to display my images in a perfect manner

here is my html code:

```
<div id="photos">
            <h3>Photo title</h3>
            <P class="like"><a href="#">Like</a> </P>
            <p class="date">date </p>
            <div id="image">
                <img src="something.jpg" />
            </div>
            <p class="about">about image goes here</p>

        </div>
```

Now i want to style the same like this:

http://www.desolve.org/

Comment: what is a "perfect manner"? just inspect their image with any browser developer tool, and you will get both html and css...

Comment: i have no idea how to implement this that's why i put it here . Any way i will try  update my css part here as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make your image like that wall post i did it in below given fiddle link.

http://jsfiddle.net/zWS7c/1/

Comment: Thank you for your time and interest to help me out.i want  the title like and date must be aliened in the same line. So i changed the css like this #photos .like,#photos .date{
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 0.8em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:50px;
}

Answer (score 1):

**Css**

```
    #photos{
margin:10px;
    border:solid 1px red;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;

}
#photos h3{
font-size:18px;
}

.date, .like{
text-align:right;
}

.about{
margin:10px;
}
#image img{
width:100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="photos">
            <h3>Photo title</h3>
            <P class="like"><a href="#">Like</a> </P>
            <p class="date">date </p>
            <div id="image">
                <img src="http://www.desolve.org/_images/chicago_banner.jpg" />
            </div>
            <p class="about">about image goes here</p>

        </div>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/46ESp/

and now set to according to **your layout** as like **margin** **padding** **with** or **height**

Answer (score 1):

I think you need like this

http://jsfiddle.net/VwPna/

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp  you learn easily... and also you can check other website css from firebug in your browser.

below code is that you given site css for banner class.

```
.banner {
    background: url("../_images/gallery_banner.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 350px;
    margin-bottom: 4em;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 3.9%;
    position: relative;
}
```

same way you can give more style their.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way it is made on the link you gave.

HTML:

```
<div class="banner">
  <h1>We love urban photography</h1>
  <p>
    We’re betting you do to. Welcome to our site, a growing collection of galleries taken by a  small group of passionate urban photographers. Visit our galleries, buy some of our prints, or drop us a line. While you’re at it, feel free to submit a gallery of your own.
    <strong>Welcome</strong>
    .
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.banner {
    background: url("../_images/gallery_banner.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 350px;
    margin-bottom: 4em;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 3.9%;
    position: relative;
}

.banner h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    padding-top: 290px;
}

.banner p {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(123, 121, 143, 0.8);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    height: 350px;
    padding: 1% 1% 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 21%;
}
```

You only need to translate that to your id's, classes and form, then you have it

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special that they've done on the reference web site. They've used the image as a background property of a div `class="preview"`.
Here is the **(x)HTML**:

```
<section class="chicago">
  <h2><a href="chicago.htm" title="Chicago gallery">Chicago</a></h2>
  <p class="pubdate">
    <time datetime="2011-04-24" pubdate="">April 2011</time>
  </p>
  <div class="preview"><a href="chicago.htm" title="Chicago gallery"></a></div>
  <p class="caption">Big wind, big shoulders. See a different side of Chicago.</p>
</section>
```

And the corresponding **CSS**

```
.chicago .preview {
background: url(../_images/sm_chicago_banner.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

You can always sneak-peek by right mouse click on the website and choosing "View Page Source" or something similar, depending on your browser :)